# Why doesn't Eren do MUCH more with his abilities?

Tags: attack-on-titan

So, in the final chapter of the manga, Eren appears to use the abilities of

> the Founding Titan to influence Dina (as a pure titan) away from eating Bertolt.

This is enabled by Eren's ability to

> perceive the past, the future, and the present simultaneously, and use the founder Ymir's power while in the Paths.

I'm confused as to the limits of this ability, given that there are SO many different things that he could have done to more effectively resolve the situation and achieve his goals. For instance, couldn't he have just

> directed ALL of the pure titans away from Shiganshina District altogether? Or have stripped Reiner, Bertolt, and Annie of their shifting abilities just before they attacked in the first place? Or even started the rumbling then and there

if that was truly his end goal at this point in the story?

I'm curious if there is some sort of supported explanation that would prevent him from doing so. The fact that he was able to

> influence Dina at all (and was thus able to influence events from his current position in non-linear time)

makes me wonder what he was capable of, and I'm not sure if there is a character motivation that would prevent him from doing any of the above as an alternative to what we see happen, if he was able to. He could have

> saved his entire family, all of his friends, and still destroyed the entire outside world

just like he wanted when he

> first started the rumbling.

The way that

> time

works in the series is a little messy, what with the

> retrocausality paradox

that allows Eren to

> cause a lot of the events of the story

using abilities he gains through...

> causing a lot of the events of the story.

Even so, assuming there is only supposed to be one

> immutable timeline

I feel like it still makes more sense for it to have just diverted very early on with Eren using the

> founder abilities

before the story even begins. How this would be explained... I don't know. All of the events of the story need to have to have happened already for Eren to get to this point, but if

> getting to this point is what caused the events of the story to happen (saving Bertolt by influencing Dina, influencing his father to steal the Founding Titan and transfer the Attack Titan in the first place, etc.)

then that seems to enable some hand-waving anyway. Is this just a bit of a plot hole to me, or am I just fundamentally misunderstanding how

> time and/or titan powers

work in the setting?

Answer (score -1):

Sincerely, from my heart, i was about to write a 7 page paragraph debunking everything, but then i realised that i read some of the things wrong and i , too, have no idea how he used some of his powers that do not require royal blood and didn't use them to influence, idk, Ymir from letting out the pigs. And i have ,too, no idea how he influenced Dina to eat Carla...

But, the answer to your question, he doesn't have royal blood, he can't use any of the Founder's powers.
I know that when he looked in the past with Zeke, he saw Grisha looking in the future thru Eren's eyes and thus he took advantage of the situation and influenced Grisha to steal the Founder. But the  rest.. The rest makes no absolute sense